# Coin Tossing game with Array to hold values

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, button

I am just learning basics of Javascript but know Java a good amount, I KNOW I AM DOING THIS WRONG, just looking for the correct way to do this.
I am trying to have a number entered into a text field and generate as many random numbers between 1-2 as the text field number specifies. Then store those numbers (A bunch of 1's and 2's) in an array and then cycle through the array with a for loop to count how many Heads or Tails there was, and print it.

Expected output: //Number inputted is 10.
Number of heads = 7 and number of tails = 3

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Coin Tosser</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>COINTOSSER</h1>

    <div id = "NumOfTosses">
        <input type = "text" id ="num">
    </div>
    <button id = "click" type="button">Start Tossing</button>

    <script>

    var numT = document.getElementById('num').value 
    document.getElementById('click').onclick = toss;
     
    
    
    function toss(){
    
        var tossArray = [];
    for(var i = 0;i<numT;i++){
    var rng = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    tossArray.push(rng);
    }   
    
    var heads = 0;
    var tails = 0;
    for(var j = 0;j<tossArray.length;j++){
            if(tossArray[j] == 0){
            heads++;
        }else{
            tails++;
        }
    }    
    
    alert("Number of heads = " + heads + " and number of tails = " + tails);
    }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You just need to move `var numT = document.getElementById('num').value` inside the `toss()` function. (you need to access the input value each time toss() is called)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've commented where I've made changes and why.

The key points are that since you are counting 2 values, you can just store the count of each value in an index of an array, rather than fill an array with a new value each time one of 2 options happen.

This lets you cut out the counting loop, making your program much more efficient, always try to count as you add rather than add then count at the end.

Also, you need to refresh the `rng` value each time the method is called, so I moved it into the top of the function.

Give it ago!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Coin Tosser</title>
    <style>
      
      /*Fun CSS added */
      @keyframes flip{
        50%{
          transform: rotate(181deg);
        }
        100%{
          transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
      }
      html{
        background-color:lightgrey;
      }
      h1{
        background-color:grey;
        border-radius:25px;
        border:1px solid black;
      }
      button{
        background-color:gold;
        border-radius:25px;
        padding:5%;
      }
      button:hover {
        animation-name:flip;
        animation-duration:1s;
      }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>COINTOSSER</h1>

    <div id = "NumOfTosses">
        <input type = "text" id ="num">
    </div>
    <button id = "click" type="button">Start Tossing</button>

    <script>

    document.getElementById('click').onclick = toss;
     
    
    
    function toss(){
    
        var numT = document.getElementById('num').value // Move numT initalization to method so it is set each time the method is run 
        var tossArray = [0,0];// change array to just count each index.
//E.G, if 1 happens '4' times, tossArray[1] will be 10.
        for(var i = 0;i<numT;i++){
          var rng = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
          tossArray[rng]=tossArray[rng]+1;
        }
      alert("Number of heads = " + tossArray[0] + " and number of tails = " + tossArray[1]);
    }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```